# how can i make listview itmes open meny url in webview?

Tags: android

I tried several times to do an example like the picture in android but failed
Is it possible to help with code example?
To make this application[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tlr6.png)

Comment: For two buttons make on activity with that. After that next Activity make with listview or recyclerview. and Third make the webview which loads your URL from previous activity click.

Comment: @NitinPatel thank u but can u explain thes with exampel please

Comment: Where do you stuck? All codes for question are to much. Lets say, have you made first activity two screen button?